# asp.net mvc 3 windows authentication

Tags: windows, asp.net-mvc-3, authentication

I am using windows authentication with asp.net mvc.
When I watch fiddler for requests, I see that most of the requests are denied first,
then in second or third try, they work.
I don't see a 401 page in the browser, but why is it like that.
for the home/index thing:
First I get a 401.2.: Access is denied.
Second I get a HTTP Error 401.1 - Unauthorized
Third, it works.
This is also true for jquery ajax calls. They work at second or third tries mostly.
I am using iis express.
I already added the 
    
    
in web.config.
Any ideas?
Thanks.